# filter with special character in ElasticSearch 6.0.0

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I am trying to filter all data which contains some special character like '@', '.','/' etc. But not able to succeed.

I am willing to fetch the city which contains the @ or dot(.), so i need a query which provide me the output that contains the special character.

I am quite new here in Elasticsearch query. So please help me.

Thanks

Below is index:

````
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 4,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "student",
        "_type" : "data",
        "_id" : "2",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "Mirja",
          "city" : "pune @ bandra",
          "contact number" : 9723124343
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "student",
        "_type" : "data",
        "_id" : "4",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "Rohan",
          "city" : "BBSR /. patia",
          "contact number" : 9723124343
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "student",
        "_type" : "data",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "Diya",
          "city" : "pune_bandra",
          "contact number" : 9723124343
        }
      }
      }
    ]
  }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the analyzer on your city field. If it's standard analyzer, it will remove special characters when creating tokens. Instead use the below mapping on city field and search using a regular match query

```
PUT test_index
    {
      "mappings": {
        "properties": {
          "city": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "custom_analyzer"
          }
        }
      },
      "settings": {
        "analysis": {
          "analyzer": {
            "custom_analyzer": {
              "type": "custom",
              "filter": [
                "lowercase"
              ],
              "tokenizer": "whitespace"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```